# Bison - what is the result?

Tags: bison

I know that using bison I get a parser LALR, but is it true to say that this parser is deterministic finite automata ( and deterministic finite automata with stack ) ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the result of bison is [deterministic pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_pushdown_automaton), *not* a finite automaton.  This is an entirely different class of automaton.

Of course, since it is run in a physical computer, it has finite limits (it does not allow for infinite stack space), but as a theoretical construct, it is quite different from a finite automaton.  You can to some extent describe a DPDA as 'just' a DFA plus an unbounded stack, but that really misses the point.

Comment: Thank you.  Can I say that parser generated by bison is a kind of deterministic pushdown automation ?